# Pandoc / Markdown: References on last page

Tags: pdftex, cross-referencing, pandoc, markdown

Currently I am writing a document. And I have written most in Markdown with some embedded LaTeX.

[image: Example reference]

However, now all references are now placed on the page where they are defined. Is it possible to move all references to the last page? So I can have a "sources" section?

Comment: Do  you mean you want to use endnotes (and not footnotes)? Or that you want to have a bibliography or works cited section?

Comment: Hi, bibliographies seems to be what I was looking for. I've found [this](http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=3907111) and switched to inline LaTeX. It would be neat if that was possible in MarkDown style, since that is a little less verbose. But it works for now.

Comment: Pandoc does bibliographies with its [citeproc module](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-citeproc). I certainly wouldn't want to do it by hand either....

Comment: The syntax you used above is for *footnotes* (not references). For a lot of insight to people new to Pandoc and reference-styling with CSL, see this GitHub repository: ***[github.com/KurtPfeifle/pandoc-csl-testing](https://github.com/KurtPfeifle/pandoc-csl-testing)***.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Pandoc` can use a number file formats (.bib, .ris, etc.) to generate your bibliography. Have a look at the documentation [here](http://pandoc.org/README.html#citations).
You need to put a header like:

`# References #`

into your .md document and your references need to look like:

`[^ref1]: See @Author1, p. 20`.

As noted in the comments, you also need to include `--filter pandoc-citeproc` to generate the bibliography.

Comment: See also this GitHub repository: [github.com/KurtPfeifle/pandoc-csl-testing](https://github.com/KurtPfeifle/pandoc-csl-testing).

Comment: The answer should be updated for pandoc 2.11, see: https://pandoc.org/releases.html#pandoc-2.11-2020-10-11